# Angular 2 forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, lite-server

I am developing an  application in angular 2 + typeScript+
 lite server.I found a very rare behavior of it.I had developed a web page which includes text box.If I hit the web page in 2 different browsers of 2 different machines, my web page pops up correctly but  if I type any values to form text box in one browser of one client machine, even text box of other browser of other client machine also filled up with this value.Please help me.If i input something in one browser, it is affected other browsers of other machines as well.Please help me.

Comment: That's the browsersync feature of your development web server you're using (express).

Comment: Hi Günter Zöchbauer, How to disable browser-sync.Nothing worked out for me.Please help.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510840/how-to-disable-cross-device-action-mirroring-functionality-of-browsersync-ghos

Comment: Hey Gunter, You are awesome bro.It helped me a lot.Thanks a lot.