# Angular 2 disable mirror of browsersync

Tags: angular

I use a template for my Angular 2 project. This project doesn't use gulp, or webpack. I'm really new on Angular 2. If I open a multiple web browsers on different computers it mirror all of I do on specific one. How can I disable this? I don't see any config file of my port (it is 3000 but I don't know how to change it) or any config file for browser sync... I'm so confused!

Also, I start my project with this command:

```
npm start
```

Here is my files:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

```
systemjs.config.js

/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
      'ng2-toasty': 'node_modules/ng2-toasty/bundles/index.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      "angular2-jwt": {
                "defaultExtension": "js"
            },
    }
  });
})(this);


package.json

{
  "name": "cayena-oak",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard-angular.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard-angular/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.2",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "angular2-chartist": "~0.10.1",
    "angular2-google-maps": "~0.16.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "chartist": "~0.9.8",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "~1.1.16",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "~0.19.41",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.17",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "yargs": "^4.7.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chartist": "~0.9.33",
    "@types/core-js": "~0.9.34",
    "@types/jquery": "~2.0.34",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "~2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "ejs": ">= 0.0.1",
    "express": "~4.9.8",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39"
  }
}
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find where your browserSync instance is initialized, and change `ghostMode` to false.

Search your code repository for `browserSync.init` and see if you can see where is initialized, and then you can modify the init options. I would think it would be in `systemjs.config.js` but it's hard to say without seeing your code.

If you can't find it, try tracing through your package configuration, start at `packages.json` and find your start command, see what that runs, and what files it loads, and trace until you find the browserSync initialization.

Reference: [How to disable cross-device action mirroring functionality of BrowserSync? (GhostMode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510840/how-to-disable-cross-device-action-mirroring-functionality-of-browsersync-ghos)

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, it looks like you're using [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) in order to run your application. To override the default browsersync configuration, you need to create a file named `my-bs-config.json` to overwrite the default configuration, and put in your file:

```
{
  "ghost": false
}
```

And then also change your "start" command in package.json to run lite-server with the new configuration file, something along these lines:

```
lite-server -c my-bs-config.json
```

So your new command would be:

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server -c my-bs-config.json\" "
```

I haven't tested that to ensure it works, so you may need to tweak that command a bit to get it to work. If you have trouble, leave a comment and I'll try to fix the command for you.

[This is based off of the `lite-server` documentation, which can be found here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adam i don't see any "start" on any of my files :( i will update my answer with these files contents.

Comment: My bad! I find this on packages.json: "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" "

Comment: Check out my edit, it looks like `lite-server` uses browser sync by default, and you just need to override the configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend! I will review this and I tell you if works

Comment: Hi my friend this works like a charm! Thanks a lot. I still have a question... maybe you can help me. How can i turn this project to a production env? I see that other projects have a "dist" folder...

Comment: That's a bit out of the scope of this question. It's also pretty broad, since it's hard to know without looking at your code (specifically your `tsconfig.json` file. If your code is being built to your `dist` directory, that should be compiled, ready to run, JavaScript code. Deploying that to production is a different question though because that depends on the server you are running and how that is setup.

Comment: Ok Adam thanks for your help. Do you suggest to me to open a new question?

Comment: Yes, that would be my recommendation. In that question you should post the contents of your your `systemjs.config.js` and `tsconfig.json` files.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. Here is my new question if you can help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259004/how-to-generate-a-production-app-on-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to add;

```
{"ghostMode": false}
```

on a newly created bs-config.json to make it work.