# How to generate a production app on Angular 4?

Tags: angular

i need to build a production ready files for my firt project on Angular 4.

On my project i don't use webpack or gulp. I just use systemJS

Here are my files:

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js', 

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
      'ng2-toasty': 'node_modules/ng2-toasty/bundles/index.umd.js',
      'angular-calendar': 'node_modules/angular-calendar/dist/umd/angular-calendar.js',
      'calendar-utils': 'npm:calendar-utils/dist/umd/calendarUtils.js',
      'angular-resizable-element': 'npm:angular-resizable-element/dist/umd/angular-resizable-element.js',
      'angular-draggable-droppable': 'npm:angular-draggable-droppable/dist/umd/angular-draggable-droppable.js',
      'date-fns': 'npm:date-fns'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      "angular2-jwt": {
                "defaultExtension": "js"
            },
      "date-fns": {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
},
"compileOnSave": false,
"typeRoots": ["node_modules"],
"types": ["system"]
}
```

I'm so new on Angular and i don't know where to start for build my app sucessfully. Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: If you are new to angular, my best advice is to move your project to `angular-cli`. They have great tools to make your project production ready. And moving it is not much of a hassle

Comment: Hi my friend thanks for your comment. The problem is that i use a template that already comes on this way. I need to work on this.

Comment: But why reinvent the wheel. It's going to take a while, and a relatively big script to get your project in production. You have to find a way to pre compile it using AoT (for speed), then bundle it, minimize, uglify.. etc. All of this is done in the `cli`

Comment: Ok... it's any way to transform a this kind of project for been used with cli?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you have problems with SystemJS, check official plunk on that http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5 . If you're trying to switch to Webpack, check one of boilerplate/starter Angular+Webpack kits. Recommending angular-cli for no obvious reason is bad idea.

Comment: I'm new on Angular my friend. Sorry if i don't know how to explain well my self. I need to transform my project into a production one. I mean with a "dist" folder.

Comment: There are a lot of people that go around saying "Just use angular-cli" and the truth is, in the real world, there are many scenarios where that simply won't work.  I've ran into several already, and have had to abandon cli and webpack.  Unfortunately the vast majority of the community completely relies on those tools, so you won't have a lot of support if you run your own build configuration.